# Magento2 add custom values in collection->setOrder

Tags: magento2, collection

I need to add some custom values in setOrder() of a collection, but it is not working.

```
$collection->setOrder("((lat - ".$lat.")*(lat - ".$lat.")) + ((lng - ".$lng.")*(lng - ".$lng."))", 'ASC');
```

The final part of my collection query like this:

```
ORDER BY ((lat - -34.9226513)*(lat - -34.9226513)) + ((lng - 138.6094486)*(lng - 138.6094486)) ASC
```

Please help anybody. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've really understood what you want to do, but in order to get a correct SQL statement, you have to check if your variables are positive or negative. Or the simplest way would be to use the pgh method `abs()` which always return the positive value of a number.

Something like this should do the trick and allways give you correct SQL statement:

```
$collection->setOrder("((lat - ".abs($lat).")*(lat - ".abs($lat).")) + ((lng - ".abs($lng).")*(lng - ".abs($lng)."))", 'ASC');
```